# How to make UITextView hashtag link open another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am using this code to make my hashtags on my app a link:

```
import UIKit

extension UITextView {

func resolveHashTags(){

    // turn string in to NSString
    let nsText:NSString = self.text

    // this needs to be an array of NSString.  String does not work.
    let words:[NSString] = nsText.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    // you can't set the font size in the storyboard anymore, since it gets overridden here.
    let attrs = [
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17.0)
    ]

    // you can staple URLs onto attributed strings
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: nsText as String, attributes:attrs)

    // tag each word if it has a hashtag
    for word in words {

        // found a word that is prepended by a hashtag!
        // homework for you: implement @mentions here too.
        if word.hasPrefix("#") {

            // a range is the character position, followed by how many characters are in the word.
            // we need this because we staple the "href" to this range.
            let matchRange:NSRange = nsText.rangeOfString(word as String)

            // convert the word from NSString to String
            // this allows us to call "dropFirst" to remove the hashtag
            var stringifiedWord:String = word as String

            // drop the hashtag
            stringifiedWord = String(stringifiedWord.characters.dropFirst())

            // check to see if the hashtag has numbers.
            // ribl is "#1" shouldn't be considered a hashtag.
            let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()

            if let numbersExist = stringifiedWord.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(digits) {
                // hashtag contains a number, like "#1"
                // so don't make it clickable
            } else {
                // set a link for when the user clicks on this word.
                // it's not enough to use the word "hash", but you need the url scheme syntax "hash://"
                // note:  since it's a URL now, the color is set to the project's tint color
                attrString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "myapplink://\(stringifiedWord)", range: matchRange)
            }

        }
    }

    // we're used to textView.text
    // but here we use textView.attributedText
    // again, this will also wipe out any fonts and colors from the storyboard,
    // so remember to re-add them in the attrs dictionary above
    self.attributedText = attrString
}

}
```

I want to make it so that when the hashtag is clicked, it will open the view controller I have for my search page and search that hashtag throughout my app.

How can I do make that connection?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is in your view controller in which you will search the hashtag, have a variable that can store the information you need.

```
var tag:String = ""
```

Then in the your textview

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
        let vc:YourViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourViewControllersID") as! YourViewController
        vc.tag = attrString
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now your newly presented view controller will have the data you stored into the tag variable

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextviewDelegate Method to detect the click on hashtag:

```
// MARK: UITextViewDelegate 

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    NSLog("Click on URL\(URL)")
    fileName = URL.absoluteString
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("show_doc", sender: self)
    return true
}

// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "show_doc" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DocumentVC
        vc.fileName = self.fileName as String
    }
}
```